# jsplumb and bootstrap grid compatibility

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsplumb

There is this jsplumb working example in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/aleem86s/gpemwumh/12/

which gets corrupted if the code is surrounded by bootstrap grid divs,
like the followings

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-7" >
      existing jsfiddle code
</div>
</div>
```

**Why?** 
It exists a similar post from 2017 : [jsPlumb and Bootstrap grids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078452/jsplumb-and-bootstrap-grids)

But it turns out that using the libraries suggested doesn't work either

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/2.2.9/jsplumb.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using the libraries versions mentioned in your question or is this the example from the other post ? Because you tagged the question with bootstrap-4 (vs. 3.3.7 in your question)

Comment: you spotted a wrong tag KBell. Sorry. I'll edit immediately